# I want to send second message to Actor as new Message

Tags: scala, akka

I have two actors for example, sender:

```
class ActorSender(actroReciever: ActorRef) extends Actor{
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "RUN" => {
      val resp = Await.result(actroReciever ? "Msg", 100.seconds)
      println("receive response " + resp)
    };
    case str:String => println(str)
    case _ => println("Error type msg")
  }
}
```

reciever:

```
class ActroReciever extends Actor{
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case str:String => {
      val snd = sender()
      snd ! "MessageFirst"
      snd ! "MessageSecond"
    }
  }
}
```

And class for starting:

```
object Tester extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("system")
  val receiver = system.actorOf(Props[ActroReciever](new ActroReciever()), "receiver")
  val sender = system.actorOf(Props[ActorSender](new ActorSender(receiver)), "sender")
  sender ! "RUN"
}
```

I want to send two messages to sender(), first as reply for "ask", second msg as "new Message", which ActorSender  execute as "matching", how I can do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you know you should not use `Await`, right?

Second, `ask` (`?`) is not meant to be used within actors. `ask` creates a temporary actor which can only receive a single message. It is not your `ActorSender` receiving the answer, but the temporary actor created by ask. That's why you have the feeling you can only send 1 answer.

You are doing this wrong, you should simply send your message using `actroReciever ! "Msg"`. No need to change anything on your `ActroReciever`.